# Application crash reporting "This problem report is damaged and cannot be processed"

Tags: bug-reporting

I have either an application that crashes almost straight after logging in or I have an old crash report that attempts to be reported and which fails. I'm erring towards the latter but I cannot be sure which if the two cases is true.

This results the following dialog being presented:

[image: System program problem detected dialog]

Clicing [Report problem ...] results in:

[image: Invalid problem report dialog]

This sequence repeats twice and then does not return until I log out and log back in.

I have searched on Google for the phrase ["This problem report is damaged and cannot be processed"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22This%20problem%20report%20is%20damaged%20and%20cannot%20be%20processed%22) but all I am able to find are issues regarding the dialog stating "IOError(13, 'Permission denied')".

Searching Google for ["Error('Incorrect padding',)"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22Error%28%27Incorrect%20padding%27,%29%22) finds some issues but none that appear to be related to Ubuntu reporting an application crash.

My best guess is that there is a corrupt application crash report and that the tool that reports the crashes is unable to use that report.

Are application crash reports stored in a specific directory and/or log file such that I can find the offending report and delete it?

If not, what else can I try to stop this from occurring?

Comment: I seem to have the same problem at the moment. Did you ever resolve the issue?

Comment: @MichaelAquilina, no, I never got to the bottom of this. As far as I remember, this was occurring on a new PC that had faulty RAM and after a RAM replacement the issue went away. The issue has now returned and it appears possibly RAM-related once again.

Comment: I also have this problem since I installed Xubuntu 14.04 in my Acer Aspire. Deleting the content of var/crash/ as suggested in some posts doesn't help me either. Does it solve your problem?

Comment: @luchonacho Deleting the content ov `/var/crash`works for me (my RAM is flawless). Why not write it up as an answer. If you don't I will.

Answer (score 3):

**It seems this is because of faulty RAM.**

I had the same problem on 12.04. I had bad RAM. When I removed it, the problem seemed to go away.
I tried another 1 GB DIMM and the problem appeared again. I removed the 2nd DIMM and the problem continued periodically.

I looked in `/var/crash` but I don't see segmentation faults in the crash output. Just very hard to tell what / where the problem is.

My experience is that Windows could handle bad DIMMs better than Ubuntu.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: @guntbert, although it buried deeply in unneeded information, this still answers the question, namely: it is caused by bad RAM. OP commented the same conclusion on his question, so this appears to be a valid, although badly written, answer.

Comment: To ensure the OP's problem really is due to bad RAM, they may want to try booting into `memtest86+` from GRUB or a LiveDVD/USB and run the tests there.

Comment: Interesting theory Gene. My experience has been somewhat different with Windows throwing a BSOD on faulty RAM. Did you ever try testing the RAM as suggested by @ChristopherKyleHorton ?

Comment: Yeah, it very much seems like it. I bought some Chinese DDR5 RAM sticks and they are going bananas.